# What type do I need to pass to multiprocessing.Value for tables object

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, pytables

I have a `table` object that I want to pass it to multiple threads. I use `multiprocessing.Value` function to create a semaphore for that object. However, it tells me that `Float32Atom` is not hashable. Not sure what to do in this case?

```
>>> import tables as tb
>>> f = tb.open_file('dot.h5', 'w')
>>> filters = tb.Filters(complevel=5, complib='blosc')
>>> n_ = 10000
>>> W_hat = f.create_carray(f.root, 'data', tb.Float32Atom(), shape=(n_, n_), filters=filters)
>>> W_hat = Value(tb.Float32Atom(), W_hat)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 135, in Value
    return Value(typecode_or_type, *args, lock=lock,
  File "/home/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 74, in Value
    obj = RawValue(typecode_or_type, *args)
  File "/home/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 48, in RawValue
    type_ = typecode_to_type.get(typecode_or_type, typecode_or_type)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Float32Atom'
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is correct that you have only threads (and no processes), you can just use multiprocessing.Semaphore. All threads run in the same context, so you can use it for all of them.

see https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects